# Are [dlr] and [dynamic-language-runtime] suitable synonyms?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

The Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) is a .NET Framework component for dynamic programming that runs on top of the Common Language Runtime (CLR).

There is a [dynamic-language-runtime](/questions/tagged/dynamic-language-runtime) tag for questions about the DLR, whereas the tag [dlr](/questions/tagged/dlr) is known to appear on new questions every now and then, eventually being swapped for the full name. They haven't been made synonyms for some reason. Would it be appropriate to make them synonyms, or does [dlr](/questions/tagged/dlr) also mean something entirely different?

If we make [dynamic-language-runtime](/questions/tagged/dynamic-language-runtime) and [dlr](/questions/tagged/dlr) synonyms, which should be the master tag? What about [clr](/questions/tagged/clr) and the nonexistent synonym [common-language-runtime](/questions/tagged/common-language-runtime)?

Comment: Well, I'm personally not a fan of the shortcut synonyms being the masters. Imagine going to a site where everything was acronyms and you didn't know what they meant...

Comment: @animuson: [SE SO SU SF MSO SFF WA BCG RPG AD AU CS CR CG CV ELU DBA GIS GD WP UX...](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: I've had to retag [tag:dlr] a few times this past week.  I think the synonym is called for, with the verbose one being the master.